# Empty parameter parsing in a function to a switch case inside the function in swift?

Tags: swift, function, switch-statement, parameter-passing, case

"How do you parse an empty parameter in a function to a switch case inside the function"?
and in case that the param is empty go to default in the switch case

```
func namePerson (_ ID: String){
        var name:string
        
        switch ID {
        case (param has value):
            name = ID
        default:
            name = "No name was added"
            
        }
        print (name)
    }

namePerson("john")
namePerson()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using optional type for the `ID` parameter and default value of `nil`:

```
func namePerson(_ id: String? = nil) {
    var name: String
    
    switch id {
    case .some(let value):
        name = value
    default:
        name = "No name was added"
    }
    print(name)
}
```

Or, without optional, using the `isEmpty` property of `String`, like this:

```
func namePerson(_ id String = ""){
    var name: String
    
    switch id.isEmpty {
    case false:
        name = id
    default:
        name = "No name was added"
    }
    print(name)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! what if the are multiple cases that is needs to check on `case "john" print("hello john")  case "david" print("hello david")`

Comment: @dinolin you can add another `switch-case` inside first case for that.